# Microsoft CRM 4.0: How to set "valid for update" = 0 for attribute?

Tags: attributes, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I want my attribute to be disabled if the form is in update mode.

I tried to export entity xml and edit value ValidForUpdateAPI [documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa682371.aspx) but it doesn't work: when I import my customizations CRM ignore them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to do this in JavaScript during the onLoad event.  Check the crmForm.FormType attribute and then disable the field if it is '2'.

```
if (crmForm.FormType == 2)
{
   crmForm.all.fieldname.disabled=true;
}
```